# Возможности редактирования stackoverfow, и не только

Tags: поддержка, предложение

Не совсем понятно, что я могу на сайте сделать.
Я - новичок у вас, и мне приходится получать информацию в комментариях итп.

- как ответить конкретному человеку в комментариях
- как посмотреть возможности форматирования комментариев

Эту информацию я получил в ответы на вопросах в комментариях.
Много информации есть в описании меток, привилегий и.т.д. Полезной, ознакомился, спасибо.
Я понимаю, что через некоторое время я всё это буду знать. 
А может есть что-то вроде статьи FAQ?
Если нет, то может стоит добавить?

Comment: Так вроде есть же?

Comment: @Qwertiy, я имею ввиду при регистрации, чтобы она выдавалась.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Конечно, у нас есть подобные статьи:

1. [Справочный центр](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help). Все более-менее фундаментальные вопросы описаны там. (По крайней мере должны быть описаны, наполнение справки продолжается).
2. Мета.

   1. Воспользуйтесь поиском.
   2. Почитайте вопросы по метке [faq](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/faq)
3. Информация о ваших возможностях как пользователя сайта и участника сообщества есть в разделе справки «[Привилегии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)». В частности, ответы на оба ваших вопроса о комментариях есть здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment

Подробнее о привилегиях:

У разных участников сообщества разный уровень возможностей взаимодействия с содержимым сайта. Задавать вопросы и давать на них ответы могут практически все. А вот закрывать или удалять вопросы — только по достижении определённого уровня репутации. Чем больше репутации, тем участник более опытен, и ему доверяются большие возможности.

Каждой привилегии посвящён целый раздел справки. Там подробно рассказывается, что вы теперь можете делать и как эффективно пользоваться новыми инструментами.

Comment: за ссылку спасибо! Но всё же остаётся вопрос, как быть с новоприбывшими. Может всё же стоит дать сылку при регистрации на подробное описание...

Comment: Хороший комментарий. Скорее всего означает, что ссылку на справку надо вытащить в большую кнопку HELP (и разместить ее прямо перед  кнопкой ВОПРОС) из маленького незаметного текста "справка" в титульной строке, рядом с окошком поиска (может ее там многие не видят?)

Comment: @avp можно сделать тест на понимание и некоторые возможности открывать только после успешного прохождения. )

Comment: @avp вообще, согласен. Справка должна быть более заметной.

Answer (score 5):

> как ответить конкретному человеку в комментариях

Поставить знак @ перед его именем. Там даже автодополнение есть. Участник при этом получит нотификацию в свой почтовый ящик.

> как посмотреть возможности форматирования комментариев

Все [здесь](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).

Answer (score 4):

> как ответить конкретному человеку в комментариях
>   как посмотреть возможности форматирования комментариев

правее поля для ввода комментария есть «кнопка» с надписью «справка»:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

после нажатия на неё разворачивается краткая справка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

внизу которой есть [ссылка](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) на более подробное изложение.

Comment: Конечно +1, но в вопросе явно сказано, что эту информацию я ***уже*** получил в ответах на комментарии.